# Doubt about installing Ubuntu on my internal HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have 256gb SSD on my laptop with windows installed on it and 1tb HDD internally. I want to install Ubuntu only on a partition of my HDD. Is this possible? If so how? as when I tried it, it only allowed me install Ubuntu on entire HDD and not on only one partition. If I selected only one partition then it would give me "no root file system defined".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question "No root system  defined"
you need to define your partition on the Installation type page...click
on "+" .

This is to create/edit a partition.

Then, you will have to select "/" which is defined as the root.

This should solve the problem.